# Mongodb: Creating a simple like system

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I need help to get this working.
Heres what I need help with:

this works it creates only 1 entry(Id: 0) for the "User: {username}" but I want to call this method creationCollection again so if it gets the collection from before again I want to create another entry(Id: 1) and so on. So everytime I call the method again I want it to increment by 1 each time.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace YoneSql
{
    public class VotingDatabase
    {
        public async Task createCollection(string username)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/");
            var database = client.GetDatabase("_YoneLikes");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<likeSettings>($"User: {username}");
            await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<likeSettings>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _.Id));
            var settings = new likeSettings
            {
                Username = $"{username}"
            };
        }

        public class likeSettings
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Username { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it will only create an ID of 0 because the createCollection recreates all the variables each and every time

Comment: I’m a bit confused how the title and question relate to each other since there’s no mention of events in the actual question or code. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry hahaha, I forgot to change the question because I had another question I wanted help on but didn't post it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad database design. You don't create a table or collection per user. You create a *record* per user and [`$inc`rement the relevant field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/).

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Username", username);
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Inc("Likes", 1);

collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

Comment: I am trying to create something like this: https://imgur.com/FPdi7Px but thank you!

Comment: Yeah, so, that's not a proper design. If you want to count likes from one user to another, you create a table `{ userFrom, userTo, likeCount }`. You don't create a table per `userFrom`.